# static Class doesn't show same values between other classes

Tags: c++

I hope that I am providing enough information and that I've titled this correctly.

In general, I want to have a class that stores data in my application, and I need several other classes to access the same data. essentially sharing the data between multiple classes.

Short/Concise Code follows:

example.cpp (main application)

```
// example.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "AnotherClass.h"
#include "ObjectClass.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>  
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;  
//Prototype
static void do_example ( );

int main()  

{  
    do_example ( );
}

static void do_example ( ) {


    MyObject.a = 5;
    cout <<"MyObject.a value set in main application is "<<MyObject.a<<"\n";

    AnotherClass    m_AnotherClass;

    m_AnotherClass.PrintValue();

}
```

ObjectClass.h

```
class ObjectClass {
public:
    ObjectClass(); // Constructor
    int a; // Public variable
} static MyObject;
```

ObjecClass.cpp

```
#include "ObjectClass.h"

ObjectClass::ObjectClass() {

    a = 0;

}
```

AnotherClass.h

```
class AnotherClass {
public:
    AnotherClass(); // Constructor

    void PrintValue(); // Public function
    int value; // Public variable

};
```

AnotherClass.cpp

```
#include "AnotherClass.h"
#include "ObjectClass.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>  
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std; 

AnotherClass::AnotherClass() {

    value = MyObject.a;

}

void AnotherClass::PrintValue() {

    cout <<"value in AnotherClass is "<<value<<"\n";
    cout <<"it should be the same."<<"\n";
}
```

But the value is the default value of 0, as if it is a new instance of MyObject. But it should be pulling the value of 5 from the static MyObject.

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you post some real, compilable code that reproduces your problem please?

Comment: You are looking for the [Singleton design pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern)

Comment: Short / Concise Compilable code added. It's really pretty simple code. It should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A static **class instance** is a static variable itself. What you expect to happen also makes sense, however, your code does not show how the static instance is handled. In fact, if both `MyClassInstance`s refer to the same object, then you don't even need static declaration.

Also, static variables are defined in cpp files. If you define it in a header, the cpp file (compilation unit) that includes it will define a separate static variable. So, define the static object in the main cpp file and use `extern MyStaticClass` in the header file. The linker will then link the uses to the same variable.

Comment: SCC has been added above. It's pretty simple, but doesn't appear to treat the static object as containing the same data.

Comment: You need to define the static variable in exactly one cpp file and use `extern` in the header. The way you have it creates a separate object for each compilation unit.

Comment: You are correct, extern defined variables are static and do not need to be declared as such. I added extern Objectclass MyObject; to my AnotherClass.cpp and removed the static instance in the ObjectClass.h. Then I added a non-static ObjectClass MyObject declaration in the example.cpp (main). it all is working as intended. thanks :)